# Colors in Pseudocode matlab style

Tags: algorithm2e, algorithmicx, algorithmic

How do I get colours and more control over spacing in the `algorithmic` package like this:

[image]

I tried this which looks good, but has numbers:

```
\begin{enumerate}
   \item Create the cumulative sum of probabilities for each care type, thus defining the interval width
   \item \textcolor{blue}{for} jj=1:m \textcolor{gray}{\% where m is the number of nurses}
   \item Choose care type
   \item \hspace{3cm}Randomly select care length ($n$) based on care type
     \item \item \textcolor{blue}{for} ii=1:n  \textcolor{gray}{\% where n is the sequence length}
   \item\hspace{3cm} Generate a random number $w$
  \item \hspace{3cm}Check into which cumulative probability interval $w$ falls and choose the corresponding surface category
  \item update ii=ii+1
  \item update jj=i+1
  \item \textcolor{blue}{end}
  \item \textcolor{blue}{end}
\end{enumerate}
```

**But using `algorithm`**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}

  \begin{algorithmic}
\STATE\COMMENT{Create the cumulative sum of probabilities for each care type, thus defining the interval width}
  \WHILE{jj=1:m} \% where m is the number of nurses
  \STATE\COMMENT{Choose care type}
        \STATE\COMMENT{Randomly select care length ($n$) based on care type}
  \WHILE{ii=1:n} \% where n is the sequence length
        \STATE\COMMENT{Generate a random number $w$}
        \STATE\COMMENT{Check into which cumulative probability interval $w$ falls and choose the corresponding surface category}
  \ENDWHILE
  \ENDWHILE
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

Looks nasty, like this:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75116/inserting-matlab-code-in-the-appendix

Comment: I would like to use one of the algorithm packages because that mcode which I use elsewhere puts numbers down the side.

Comment: `mcode` numbers lines of listings only if you add `numbered` as an option to the package. You can turn off numbering for a single listing by adding `numbers=none` as an optional argument to that listing, or you can have it off by default (remove `numbered` from the package options) and number only those listings you want to, by adding `numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny` to the optional arguments of the listing. You can also use `\lstset` in the document to change the behaviour of all the subsequent listings.

Comment: @HCAI Please, see the link above. Just remove or comment  the lines `numbers=left, numberstyle={\tiny \color{black}}, numbersep=9pt,` from the code presented as the first answer.

Comment: You could always use the listing package which works great for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Consider using the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891) of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should get you started; additional customisation might be required.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{kw}{blue}
\definecolor{com}{rgb}{0,0.6,0.3}

\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

% redefine keywords
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicfunction{\textcolor{kw}{function}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicwhile{\textcolor{kw}{while}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicfor{\textcolor{kw}{for}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicif{\textcolor{kw}{if}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicelse{\textcolor{kw}{else}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicend{\textcolor{kw}{end}}

% new keywords
\algnewcommand\Break{\textcolor{kw}{break}}%
\algnewcommand\Continue{\textcolor{kw}{continue}}%

% redefine loops
\algdef{SE}[WHILE]{While}{EndWhile}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1}{\algorithmicend}%
\algdef{SE}[FOR]{For}{EndFor}[1]{\algorithmicfor\ #1}{\algorithmicend}%
\algdef{C}[IF]{IF}{ElsIf}[1]{\algorithmicelse\algorithmicif\ #1}%

% redefine comments
\algrenewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{{\color{com}\%#1}}

\begin{document}

\ttfamily

\begin{algorithmic}
\State Create the cumulative sum of probabilities for each care type,
    thus defining the interval width
\For{jj=1:m} \Comment{ where m is the number of nurses}
\State Choose care type
\State Randomly select care length ($n$) based on care type
\For{ii=1:n} \Comment{ where n is the sequence length}
\State Generate a random number $w$
\State Check into which cumulative probability interval $w$ falls
    and choose the corresponding surface category
\State update ii=ii+1
\State update jj=i+1
\EndFor
\EndFor
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jubobs, this is really helpful. I have a small additional question: in your example, the "Check into which ... surface category" line spans two lines, and the second line is not indented. Is there a way to modify the algorithmicx to also have the second line indented to the same (or other) extent?? Thanks